# jQuery - send data as POST, and abort?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

**Edit: The code is now working, based on responses. However, abort still doesn't work. It is updating the field with the POST request, even after I abort. How do I handle this?**

I am trying to take the data from a form, and send it to a PHP file and get the result.

This is the code that I was using, which worked perfectly. However, as far as I'm aware - it's impossible to use abort with this.

```
var xhr = $.post("compareusername.php", { userCreation:$('#userCreation').val() 
}, function(data){
$("#userRegexJavascriptResponse").text(data);
});
```

I tried adding this. The function call works, but abort does not appear to - it still updates.

```
xhr();
xhr.abort();
```

---

I tried changing my code to this,  but then it just breaks. I think it's the data line, I don't believe I'm doing it right:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "accountcreation.php",
data: "userCreation": #userCreation.val(),
success: function(msg){
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
}
});
xhr();
```

Comment: Any specific reason to use abort? it broke due to syntax error. corect syntax is data: {"userCreation": $('#userCreation').val()},

Comment: `abort` will just stop the client side listener(the fail handler will get executed with status `abort`)... it will not stop the server side processing

Comment: @WebArtifice Thanks for the syntax, that worked! Unfortunately, abort doesn't work :( It still returns the data from the request.

Comment: @ArunPJohny That's all I wanted, but unfortunately it's still updating the field on the client side. Any suggestions?

Comment: then the success handler is called before the abort call.... did you check that

Comment: @ArunPJohny I don't think I follow.. I want it to produce the success message, but only if I do not first abort **before it finishes.** How would I code that?  Thanks! Right now, I do xhr(); and xhr.abort(); right after it, for testing.

Answer (score 0):

When sending data to a server via `jQuery.ajax` method, the arguments to that method do indeed take an optimal parameter as part of the JSON object argument 1. This parameter is called `data`

You haven't shown HTML. But, you need to capture the default event that is dispatched when the form is submitted (user clicking on submit action catalyst), and then respond appropriately. The basic algorithm is this:

FORM_CLICK ->

- prevent default browser behavior
- send serialized form data to server via XMLHTTPRequest object
- get response from XMLHTTPRequest object (wait for response)
- done

And that is it. The connection is then closed, as far your JavaScript code is concerned. After your responds and exits the request, the client-side code (JavaScript) is complete.

To actually send it with jQuery, in your (presumably,) context, you would add a member element to your object:

```
{ 
  ...
  ...
  data : $(this).serialize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the data doesn't look valid. Try this:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "accountcreation.php",
    data: "userCreation=" + $('#userCreation').val(),
    success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});
xhr();
```